# Users overwriting each other's progress

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

Hi I'm building a basic Battleships app using python and google app engine. You can see it here: http://battleships-1098.appspot.com

I'm relatively new to coding so please excuse me if I'm missing some fairly basic knowledge but I've been struggling with the same problem for a couple of weeks now.

The app works almost perfectly with one user, but as soon as multiple users start playing games (independently) they start overwriting each other's data.

For example: the app asks for two names but when another user starts playing these will be overwritten by the names the new player picks. e.g,

Player 1 picks the names Fred and George and starts playing. All is fine.

But then player 2 starts playing a completely separate game and picks the names Anne and Rita. This actually overwrites the names in player 1's game too. Names aren't the only bits of data that are overwritten--shots recorded do too.

I've implemented a google sign in to try and create individual sessions for each user in an effort to stop this, but this hasn't solved this issue. I'd massively appreciate some help with working out what I'm doing wrong! *(please excuse some of the inefficiencies in here--I'm just trying to get it working before I make the code better!)*

```
from google.appengine.api import users
import jinja2
import os
import random
import webapp2


jinja = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))   

board1 = []
board2 = []

def generate_board(board):
    for row in range(0,5):
        row = ['0']*5
        board.append(row)

generate_board(board1)    
generate_board(board2)     

boats = 0

def generate_boats(board):
    for boats in range(5):
        i = random.randint(0,4)
        n = random.randint(0,4)
        board[i][n] = '1'
        boats += 1

generate_boats(board1)
generate_boats(board2)


def user_shoots(board, col_shot, row_shot):
    a=int(col_shot)-1
    b=int(row_shot)-1
    if board[a][b]=='1':
        board[a][b]='X'
        return True
    else:
        return False

i_a=0
i_b=0
t=1.5
s_a=3
s_b=3
h_sunka = []
h_misseda = []
h_sunkb = []
h_missedb = []
c_a = {}
c_b = {}
values={}
greet={}


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            greet['nickname'] =  user.nickname()
            greet['url'] = users.create_logout_url('/')
            template0=jinja.get_template('greeting.html')
            self.response.out.write(template0.render(greet))
        else:
            greet['link2'] = users.create_login_url('/')
            template01=jinja.get_template('greeting2.html')
            self.response.out.write(template01.render(greet))


class GamePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        name1=self.request.get("name1")
        name2=self.request.get("name2")
        values['name1']=name1
        values['name2']=name2
        c_a['name1']=name1
        c_a['name2']=name2
        c_b['name1']=name1
        c_b['name2']=name2
        template3 = jinja.get_template('game_body.html')
        self.response.out.write(template3.render(values))

    def post(self):
        global i_a
        global s_a
        global t
        if int(t)%2!=0:
            if t%1==0:
                template3 = jinja.get_template('game_body.html')
                self.response.out.write(template3.render(c_a))
                t+=0.5
            else: 
                col_shot=self.request.get("column")
                row_shot=self.request.get("row")
                e='missed'
                f='sunk'
                if user_shoots(board2, col_shot, row_shot):
                    s_a-=1
                    i_a+=1
                    self.response.write('Kabbooom, good shot <br><br>')
                    h_sunka.append('a'+str(col_shot)+str(row_shot))
                    if s_a<=0:
                        self.response.write('\nAll ships down sir <br><br>')
                        self.response.write(c_a['name1'])
                        self.response.write(" wins! <br>")
                else:
                    self.response.write('You fool! You missed <br><br>')
                    i_a+=1
                    h_misseda.append('a'+str(col_shot)+str(row_shot))
                for miss in h_misseda:
                    c_a[miss]=e 
                for hit in h_sunka:
                    c_a[hit]=f
                template4 = jinja.get_template('changeturns1.html')
                self.response.out.write(template4.render(c_a))  
                t+=0.5
        else:
            if t%1==0:
                template5 = jinja.get_template('game_title2.html')
                self.response.out.write(template5.render(values))
                template6 = jinja.get_template('game_body2.html')
                self.response.out.write(template6.render(c_b))
                t+=0.5
            else: 
                col_shot=self.request.get("column")
                row_shot=self.request.get("row")
                e='missed'
                f='sunk'
                global i_b
                global s_b
                global t
                if user_shoots(board1, col_shot, row_shot):
                    s_b-=1
                    i_b+=1
                    self.response.write('Kabbooom, good shot <br><br>')
                    h_sunkb.append('a'+str(col_shot)+str(row_shot))
                    if s_b<=0:
                        self.response.write('\nAll ships down sir <br><br>')
                        self.response.write(c_b['name2'])
                        self.response.write(" wins! <br>")
                else:
                    self.response.write('You fool! You missed <br><br>')
                    i_b+=1
                    h_missedb.append('a'+str(col_shot)+str(row_shot))
                for miss in h_missedb:
                    c_b[miss]=e 
                for hit in h_sunkb:
                    c_b[hit]=f
                template7 = jinja.get_template('changeturns2.html')
                self.response.out.write(template7.render(c_b))  
                t+=0.5

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([

('/', MainHandler), ('/game', GamePage)
],  debug=True)
```

Comment: You have a whole heap of problems with you approach.  Game state is in the handler. However you have no garuntee that any game will be handled by the same request handler/instance. You need to consider storing the game state in the datastore and binding a specific game to the users session. Assuming you want to have a player in more than one game at a time.  This is probably a basic excercise  and you don't need that more complex capabilities however appengines architecture does not match you implementation strategy.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for your response. Do you know of any resources that you could point me to to help me learn about storing the game state in the datastore and binding a specific game to the user's session?

Comment: Sessions and http state: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~csev/books/gae/lectures/07-Cookie-Session-Print.pdf sessions in webapp2: https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll read these

Comment: I also found this Udacity tutorial https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud858/l-3886008611/e-3947078756/m-3974418735 in case anyone else is struggling with database stuff